# vba-excel: how to exclude copying a range of cells with for loop and if statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

I have this code:

```
lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

For a = 1 To lr
    If (Sheet1.Cells(a, 1) = Date Or Date - 1) And (Sheet1.Cells(a, 2) = "AA" Or Sheet1.Cells(a, 2) = "BB" Or Sheet1.Cells(a, 2) = "CC") And Sheet1.Cells(a, 3) = array(0) Then
        Call ActivateSheet
        Sheet1.Range(Cells(a, 4), Cells(a, 10)).Copy
        Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next a

I have two columns with data in them. In column **A** we have there the value of DATE which i'll call **currentDate** and the value of DATE-1 which i'll call **yesterDate**. In column **B** I could have **three** different values, which are **AA**, **BB**, and **CC**. My if statement above (i apologize for how noobish the code looks, i'm still trying to learn VBA. ;P) basically checks if the values in column **A** are either the **currentDate OR yesterDate** and checks if the values in column **B** are either **AA**, **BB**, OR **CC**. THEN, if the values of column **A** and column **B** are any combinations of the given values, it will copy that range of cells and paste it on **Sheet2**.

So here's what I want to happen. From all the possible combinations of the values given, there's one combination **I don't want to copy** and that combination is **yesterDate && CC**.

I only want my code to copy **yesterDate && AA**, and **yesterDate && BB**, and **currentDate && CC**. All other combinations like **currentDate && AA or currentDate && BB** will not likely to happen based from the user input.

I just want to exclude **yesterDate && CC** to be copied by my code. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I got one for you. Try with this.

```
Public Sub checkAndCopy()

    Dim rowCount, row As Integer
    Dim dateCell, valueCell, combinationCell As String
    Dim isValid As Boolean

    'Getting row count from Sheet1
    rowCount = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    'Looping all row from Sheet1.
    For row = 1 To rowCount

        'getting cell values
        dateCell = Sheet1.Range("A" & row)
        valueCell = Sheet1.Range("B" & row)
        combinationCell = Sheet1.Range("C" & row)

        'Sometime one of these cell should be blank or wrong date value.
        'So, I added checking to avoid it.
        'If these two cell are not empty, check date is valid or not.
        If dateCell <> "" And valueCell <> "" Then

            'If date value is valid, go on checking for copy cell.
            If IsDate(dateCell) Then

                'Reset isValid flag.
                isValid = True

                'You just want to exclude yesterday & CC.
                'So, I only check for it.
                If dateCell = Date - 1 And valueCell = "CC" Then
                    isValid = False
                End If

                'If both cell values are valid and also combination cell is valid, copy and paste cell.
                If isValid And combinationCell = array(0) Then

                    'Select cells
                    Sheet1.Range(Cells(row, 4), Cells(row, 10)).Select

                    'Copy cells
                    Selection.Copy

                    'Paste cells
                    Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

                    'Reset clipboard
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks awesome! I just semi gave up on it for the day and turned off my laptop lol. Will definitely try this tomorrow. Will let you know what will happen! Thanks mate!!